# Anything special about $[g(x)-g(a)]/(x-a)$?

Tags: functions

Recently I have been reviewing my knowledge about functions. During this you come across some formulas that you recognize. For example, one example included

$$\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h},$$

which I recognized as differentiation from first principles. The next example used:

$$\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}$$

Just wanted to know if this was also a hint at another topic or process, or is this just randomly picked for the exercise?

Comment: What happens when you replace $h$ with $a-x$?

Comment: If you take $a=x+h$, then you get the first formula. No difference in terms of differentiation.

Comment: Rather than thinking of these as "differentiation," you can think of the second as the slope of the line segment between $(x,g(x))$ and $(a,g(a)),$ when $a\neq x.$ The first is the slope of the segment from $(x.g(x))$ to $(x+h,g(x+h)),$ when $h\neq 0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the same difference quotient, expressed in terms of two nearby points rather than one point and the distance to a nearby point.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same process you already know--it's differentiation. In particular, with a limit substitution we have $$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x_0+h) - g(x_0)}{h} = \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{g(x) - g(x_0)}{x - x_0}  $$ So, this is just another expression for the difference quotient.